# How can I put a WooCommerce product-frame via PHP in a HTML site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm a beginner who learns about WooCommerce and right now I have a project where I need to make from an HTML Website to a WordPress Theme where you can put a product and list on the page.

Can someone give me an article or share some information with me? Here is a photo of how I want to make it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGCCH.jpg The line is facing the location for products but I don't know how to make a PHP and integrate to all products insert in this space with my .css. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use woocommerce such a rest api in your app check the link : https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/

this article show you how to link your woocommerce store with php : https://iconicwp.com/blog/woocommerce-api-php/

Comment: I don't know if this is what I need but I have a question. It's this article good for me if I use WordPress and I want WordPress to connect my HTML Theme.